# string format and line break

Tags: android

I want to code finish string format, I have a

```
String s="19831014"+"linknum"+i+"cool";
```

I want to this s have a format link this:

```
s=<red>19831014</red>+"//n"  //line break  
  +<green>"linknum"</green> +i+"cool"
```

Can you help?

Comment: I don't get what you want. Also, a line-break is archived by using `\n` not `//n`.

Comment: can you tell me how to add color to the string?

Comment: Strings don't have colors. However you can use something like HTML and a suited parser to add color-informations. But Strings themselves don't have colors.

Comment: loadHtml i think not trust red tag

Comment: You could use the [`<font>`-tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` doesnot have Color but the thing that displays a `String` has.

But you can convert your `String` object to [`SpannableString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) which allows user to add effects like Bold, italics, Underline, Colored Text Portions etc.

if you want to display String with different colors you have to use [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html)

For  example :

```
 SpannableString colouredString =new SpannableString("Red, Green, Blue.");

 colouredString.setSpan(new  ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFF0000), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 colouredString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF00FF00), 5, 11, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 colouredString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF0000FF), 12, colouredString.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

For changing the Background Color you have to use [`BackgroundColorSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html) :

For Example :

```
coloredString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 8, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

now you can use this `colouredString` for showing it in `EditText` and `TextView`

For giving different styles you can use [StyleSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html)

Reference Example: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext

Answer (score 6):

```
String s="19831014\n"+"linknum"+i+"cool";
```

"\n" is a line break.

Comment: can you tell me how to add color?

Comment: a string does not have color. a textview does. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textColor

Comment: Strings don't have color.  Things that display strings do.